# State of the stack after goto

Tags: c, stack, goto

In the following C code, `f` calls `g`, and `g` calls `h`. Notice the `goto` in `h`, however: it will jump back to `f` if `a` satisfies a certain condition.

```
void h(int a)
{
    if (a > 10)
        goto out;
}

void g(int a, int b)
{
    h(a);
}

void f(int a, int b)
{
    g(a, b);
    return;
out:
    printf("b: %d\n", b);
}
```

My question is: how will the stack be if the `goto` is triggered? Will `g` and `h` be unstacked? And will `f` still print the right value of `b`? (or will it print it right only in some cases when I am lucky?)

(Please, I don't want to discuss if this is a good practice, or if this should be used at all. Also, consider that the actual code is complicated enough so that the compiler won't be smart enough to, e.g., optimize `g` out)

[I can give details on why I am doing this, if it matters -- I don't think it does]

Comment: AFAIK labels must be locale to function scope. You can't do that in standard C.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for me, like LPs comment states, gotos are locale to function scopes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "goto" into different function in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355110/how-to-goto-into-different-function-in-c)

Comment: There is no stack in the C standard, your question lacks a foundation. And your code is invalid.

Comment: It is horribly bad to jump from code within one function to code in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will result in undefined behavior in standard C.

From 6.8.6.1/1 of the [C Language Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

> The identifier in a goto statement shall name a label located
>   somewhere in the enclosing function. A goto statement shall not jump
>   from outside the scope of an identifier having a variably modified
>   type to inside the scope of that identifier.

Answer (score 4):

The question is void, because it simply cannot be done like this: you only can `goto` within a function, not between functions.

For jumping between functions, you can use `setjmp`/`longjmp`.

Comment: There is also no need for a stack in C from the language standard.

Comment: .. where the fun thing of `setjmp`/`longjmp` is that their designer was well aware of potential stack problems (in implementations that use it) so they were designed to *not* use the same stack as regular functions. (See lots and lots of Stack Overflow questions, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7969075/2564301).)

Answer (score 1):

A goto statement in C programming provides an unconditional jump from the 'goto' to a labeled statement **in the same function**.

Labels are local to a single function, you cannot jump between different functions.

**NOTE − In my opinion the use of goto statement is highly discouraged.**

ref: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_goto_statement.htm

Comment: "Use of goto statement is highly discouraged" is a subjective. I agree to it only for the "general" case. There are cases where using `goto` is the easiest way to go, e. g. error handling.

Comment: I agree @glglgl. The Linux kernel is full of examples where it is fit

Comment: `goto` has its applications **in C**. So no, it is not discouraged. That's what CS profs tell the students. The profs with some insight in practical programming later weaken this statement.

Comment: @IshayPeled Linux Kernel is far from a good example to "how to code".... my personal opinion.

Comment: @glglgl Can agree, but is the easiest way for who?.. Probably for lazy coders... ;)

Comment: @LPs it is your personal opinion (; Dijkstra's take on this is gotos are a disaster and Linus take is its good.

Comment: Yes, obviously it is my personal opinion, .. :-)

Comment: @LPs Or maybe programmers who think/know that `goto` is a lesser evil than several levels of indentation.

Comment: @IshayPeled Dijkstra's take on this is gotos are a disaster in languages where you can avoid them easily. AFAIR he doesn't completely reject them.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this since labels are local to each particular function. However, the nearest standard equivalent is the setjmp() and longjmp() pair of functions. That should work. :)

Comment: setjmp() and longjmp() are not exactly equivalents IMHO..

Comment: I agree but for a beginner's needs, it should suffice. :)